# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

Tags: java, exception

my program is meant to read from a txt and print certain parts of it. when i try to set Double d4 it gives me an error saying that string is 
empty although it's not. and it's also not an issue of formatting since d1-5 worked fine when i removed the line. i also printed data[5] and that showed the proper line from the txt.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class AAAAAA {
    public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException {

    final String fileName = "classQuizzes.txt";
//1)
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    //declarations 
    String input;
    double total = 0.0;
    double num = 0;
    double count = 0;
    double average = 0;
    String lastName;
    String firstName;
    double minimum;
    double max;


//2) process rows   
    input = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(input); 
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

       String line = sc.nextLine();
       System.out.println(line);

    // split the line into pieces of data separated by the spaces
       String[] data = line.split(" ");

    // get the name from data[]
       System.out.println("d5 " +data[4]);
       firstName = data[0];
       lastName = data[1];
       Double d1 = Double.valueOf(data[2]);
       Double d2 = Double.valueOf(data[3]);
       Double d3 = Double.valueOf(data[4]);
       Double d4 = Double.valueOf(data[5]);
       Double d5 = Double.valueOf(data[6]);


    // do the same...
    System.out.println("data " + d3);
         total += d1 + d2 + d3  + d5;
         count++;

   //find average (decimal 2 points)
               System.out.println(count);
               average = total / count;
               System.out.println("Total = " + total);
               System.out.println("Average = " + average);

//3) class statistics




    //while
       }       
         System.out.println("Program created by");
     }
}
```

Comment: *when i try to set Double d4 it gives me an error saying that string is empty although it's not* - Why should the JRE tell you that a string is empty if it's not? How do you know it's not? Did you try debugging your program?

Comment: yes, i put a print line before setting it and that showed the value that was expected

Comment: Instead of describing the exception, please [edit] your question to include the full text of the stacktrace.

Comment: What's the exact error message?  What's the exact line which produces the error?  What are the exact values observed during debugging (not assumed) of the variables on that line?

Comment: i just edited the question with the error

Comment: @Stuwuf You didn't. You printed `data[4]`, not `data[5]`

Comment: @BackSlash i was testing other stuff this was just the latest edit.

Comment: @Stuwuf: Put "other stuff" aside for a moment and focus on the question being asked.  The JRE is not *lying* to you.  If you're getting an exception, it's for a reason.  Forgo your assumptions for a moment and debug to observe the values and behavior of the code.  When your debugging encounters a specific operation performed on specific values which produces an unexpected result, *that's* the information you're looking for.  What was the operation?  What were the values?  What was the observed result?  What result did you expect?  Why?

Comment: To be clear, no one's going to believe your word over the JVM's. We can try to point you to your mistake, but only if you provide all the necessary information to make the scenario clear and reproducible, i.e., a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line might not be empty, but when you split it at spaces, if there are two spaces in a row, you will get empty strings in the split. To prevent this, change

```
String[] data = line.split(" ");
```

to

```
String[] data = line.split(" *");
```

or, perhaps better, since it will deal with tabs and other white space:

```
String[] data = line.split("\\s*");
```

To track down these kinds of problems yourself (and to verify that I've diagnosed the problem correctly), you should print out each element of the split array, as well as verify the array length is what you expect.